# Good graphing/interpreting software

Tags: software, accelerometer

Is there any software that would graph x, y, and z values as fields / time written to a sd card by a microcontroller with an accelerometer? Or would I be better off writing my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like this is offline visualization not realtime display? Like you will collect data, take the SD card out of the MCU board, plug it into a PC, and do the plotting there?

There is [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/). It was a PITA to set up on my Mac but it's pretty cool. I have only gone at it from the side of emitting data that was formatted for plotting but I think it will eat CSV and you can tell it what to do with the columns. Definitely has a learning curve and feels a bit inscrutable but it's been a valuable tool for me here and there.

There should also be tons of graphing and plotting libraries for Ruby and Python, if you are comfortable with writing some script. I have occasionally needed to graph something and just googled and picked one at random. If you are comfortable programming and your needs are not too specialized you can probably get something drawn in a few minutes.

Definitely does **not** sound like the time to write your own plotting library if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: OK, thank you. I spend most of my time in linux anyway so it sounds like gnuplot is what I am looking for. And yes, this is offline visualisation.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two independent questions: How to compute accelleration from a set of successive positions, and how to graph the accelleration magnitude.

The first is very basic physics.  See Newton.  Accelleration is the second derivative of position.

The second is a generic generic graphing problem.  Lots of software will graph things.  For simple stuff I often write data to a CSV file, and then use generic CSV plotting software.

Comment: I already know how to write and calculate the values. I already have the sd card filled with data. I was only asking about the plotting, which is there any one specific csv plotting software that rises above the others?